# request.is_secure() always returns false with uwsgi server

Tags: django, https, nginx, uwsgi

We are using Ngnix + uWSGI setup for our Django-based application.

Our problem is that `request.is_secure()` always returns **false** even though we are serving content on https.

As mentioned in the uWSGI documentation, I have set `uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme` in nginx configuration or uwsgi_params, but it is of no use.

We also have Nginx + apache based setup for the same application, there it works just fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly did you set `uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;`?

Comment: Long shot: are you on AWS? And specifically, behind ELB on AWS?

Answer (score 9):

For `gunicorn` server fixed with:

Add this line to `nginx.conf` file:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto           $scheme;
```

And add this line to `settings.py` file:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Comment: I had to add this to my site settings instead of conf file located at  ` /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved !!

We tried couple of things to fix it but couldn't get it working. 
I will put some more information here about the problem that we analyzed later on. 
Our current setup on webfaction looks like this :

WebFaction Nginx -> our nginix -> uwsgi server

what we found that there was some problem in configuration of webfaction nginx that it was passing all the traffic of (https and http) to our nginx on http protocol itself. So first we changed this setup to pass on the right traffic to right server.

Still we found that $scheme set by both nginx server is not correct, so what we finally did is to set the following in our nginx for https configuration:

```
uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME https;
```

this solved the problem as of now.

Answer (score 5):

I had half a day of hell fixing this issue, so saving everyone the headache

Firstly,

set

```
uwsgi_param   HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO    $scheme;
```

in nginx.conf

Then drop this line into settings.py

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

If you're on Django<1.4, you'll also need to enable the `django-secure` middleware

Comment: I owe you like 10 beers. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use `request.scheme` instead of `request.is_secure()` to check if we currently using `https` protocol.

Comment: one need to be little cautious about the using the request.scheme, in many cases the https connection terminates at the load balancer level. After the load balancer, it may be case that internally it may be using http only to transmit the data.

Comment: Look at Django code in main repository [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L211) it showing that `code`is_secure()`code` using scheme to detect if it is secure.

Answer (score 1):

is nginx the https terminator or you have some other server before it ?

In such a case the $scheme variable in nginx will always map to 'http'. You have to manually set it to 'https'

uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME https;

Comment: we are using webfaction, there is a webfaction nginx before our nginx and that must be the https terminator..but again we have one more similar setup where we are using nginx + apache. there is no such issue exist